# Проблемы с std::vector с++

Tags: память, vector, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос такой: создал класс Packet (для хранения информации, содержащейся в Ethernet пакете).

Packet.h

```
#pragma once

#include "vector"

typedef unsigned char UCHAR;

using namespace std;

class Packet
{
private:
    vector<UCHAR> bytes;
public:
    Packet();

    void SetBytes(UCHAR *, int);

    ~Packet();
};
```

Packet.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Packet.h"

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 1000

Packet::Packet()
{
    bytes.clear();
    bytes.assign(MAX_PACKET_SIZE, 0);
}

void Packet::SetBytes(UCHAR * newBytes, int size)
{
    bytes.clear();
    bytes.assign(size, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        bytes[i] = newBytes[i];
}

Packet::~Packet() { }
```

Помещаю все это в проект Network, который компилируется как lib.
Дальше пытаюсь использовать данный класс из этой библиотеки.

main.cpp

```
#pragma comment(lib,"..\\..\\Debug\\Network.lib")

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Packet.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Packet packet;

    UCHAR * b = new UCHAR[]{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46,
                            0x03, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04,
                            0x00, 0x01, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xa8,
                            0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xa8,
                            0x01, 0x0c};

    packet.SetBytes(b, 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция проходит удачно.
Однако запуск выдает следующее:

[image]

отладка показала, что ошибка происходит после return 0; в конце программы. дело в деструкторах или неправильном использовании vector<>?

Копаюсь в этом с сегодняшнего утра. Собственными силами разобраться не получилось. Буду признателен, если поможете.
Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:**

попробовал собрать все в 1 проекте - без использования статической библиотеки.
Все заработало. Я не понимаю в чем дело! Такой вариант меня не устраивает, поэтому необходимо найти ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вылетает даже на таком коде:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UCHAR * b = new UCHAR[] {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46,
        0x03, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x0c};

    return 0;
}
```

А на таком — нет:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UCHAR * b = new UCHAR[42] {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46,
        0x03, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x0c};

    return 0;
}
```

(разница в указании размера). Почему?

---

Посмотрел на дизассемблированный код.

В первом случае получается такое:

```
00101000  push        0  
00101002  call        operator new[] (010105Ch)
```

А во-втором — такое:

```
00101000  push        2Ah  
00101002  call        operator new[] (010105Ch)
```

То есть в первом случае аллоцируется 0 элементов, а память используется из 42-ух.

Не знаю, баг ли это Visual Studio или так по стандарту. Может быть, кто-нибудь с gcc проверит ассемблерный код?

---

По результатам обсуждения: да, это выглядит как баг Visual Studio. Такой код без указания размера вовсе не должен компилироваться.

Возможно, вы захотите использовать `std::initializer_list<UCHAR>`, либо располагать массив на стеке:

```
UCHAR b[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46,
        0x03, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x0c};
```

или даже

```
UCHAR b[] {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46,
        0x03, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x14, 0xda, 0xe9, 0x46, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xa8,
        0x01, 0x0c};
```

Comment: это были приступы паники)) я написал это, потому что хоть как-то хотел заставить это работать. Без ручного деструктора та же проблема

Comment: @pelmeshka80: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Почему размер играет значение, я не знаю. На самом деле это ARP пакет, пойманый wiresharkom, и создавался в таком виде для тестирования. В работающей проге он, естественно, будет заменен.

Спасибо!

Comment: @pelmeshka80: Пожалуйста!

@avp: Тут не обойтись без вашей помощи :)

Comment: Неплохо) буду знать, на какие грабли не стоит натыкаться))

Comment: на первый пример gcc 4.9 честно сказал

> error: too many initializers for 'unsigned char [1]'

clang 3.4:

> error: excess elements in scalar initializer

как только добавляешь 42, оба сразу успокаиваются:) и генерят нормальный ожидаемый код.

на дворе 2015 год, а студийный компилятор не может проверять такие вещи... даже если это не требуется по стандарту.

Comment: Ага, g++ 4.8 также ругается:  too many initializers for 'unsigned char [1]'

А если честно, то я совсем не понимаю, зачем в такой задаче все эти выверты.

Comment: @KoVadim, @avp: Спасибо!

Значит, это баг парсера Visual С++, он не должен был такое пропускать. Вот и хорошо.

---
@avp: насколько я понял, это упрощённый код, воспроизводящий проблему. В реальности там будет сложнее.